# php sometimes echo file_get_contents('php://input') after post form

Tags: php, docker

My question as title above, that echo displayed on the first line of the page.

I'm using Docker version 20.10.5, build 55c4c88 on Ubuntu 20.04.

When I turn down php container and restart, that echo will be disappeared

My docker setting is here https://github.com/iloveleon19/docker-server

html form

```html
    <form action="test.php" method="post">
        <label for="field">something</label>
        <input type="text" name="something">
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
```

test.php code

```php
<?php
die;
```

Comment: it look like the same issue with https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=80385&fbclid=IwAR3AsE4xKr5IJI9c0bsv_89gXiV8HK35QtGiUPtn5ozH1-wXRLWn4lmJ3bQ

Comment: What is the PHP code that you are running in the container? Is it just that one line? Any other (ex. JavaScript) code?

Comment: I edited, just like that simple code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I closed export php-fpm 9000 prot, 9000 port only use by networks in container, and that problem is solved

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
    php:
        build: "php/"
        container_name: "php_7.2-fpm"
        user: "www-data"
        restart: always
        working_dir: /var/www/html
        volumes:
            - ~/workspace:/var/www/html
            - ./php/conf.d:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
            - ./php/php-fpm.d/zzz-local.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zzz-local.conf
            - ${PHP_LOG}:/var/log
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            # - redis
        # ports:
        #     - "9000:9000"
        networks:
            - app-network
        tty: true
```